# NPM Lifecycle Scripts for Dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, package.json

NPM has detailed [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts) on the various lifecycle scripts and the order of execution in various scenarios. This documentation, lacks, however, information on the script execution lifecycle for installed dependencies. I can tell that some scripts are being run for installed packages in some scenarios, but I'm unable to find authoritative documentation on which scripts run for installed dependencies, and in which circumstances.

In particular, I'm looking for information on which lifecycle scripts executed are in dependency packages in three different scenarios, and in which order:

- `npm install` (while `<dependency_package>` is contained in the current package's `package.json`)
- `npm install <dependency_package>`
- `npm ci` (while `<dependency_package>` is contained in the current package's `package.json`).

In addition, I'm hoping to find some authoritative source on the general logic for when dependency scripts are executed, and in what order (for instance, to draw conclusions about the lifecycle scripts executed for dependencies in other scenarios).